# NSLayoutConstraint - dynamic height of a superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have three views inside a custom UITableViewCell: `self.username, self.postText, self.containerView` where `self.containerView` is the superview for the two others. I want it to be layed out like this:

```
Contrainer = self.containerView
-----------------------------
|.....5pt-margin............|
| [self.username]           |
| [self.postText]*          |
|.....5pt-margin............|
---------------------------- 
* Posttext can have a dynamic height - and the superview's height should adapt dynamically  based on this height
```

I've tried the following NSLayoutConstraint in my cell's init method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [...]
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.username,    self.postText, self.containerView);
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(5)-[self.username]-[self.postText]-(5)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It currently crashes without any log. How should the correct NSLayoutConstraint look?

Comment: I think the best way for you is creating custom UITableViewCell class, then and all your views in the way you like.

Comment: I have a custom UITableViewCell class. It's in that class I've tried to add my NSLayoutConstraint.

Comment: Your code isn't complete so it makes it difficult to help you track it down. You should use the ivars in the NSDictonaryOfVariableBindings and visual format string. Also, you can't adjust a table view row height inside a cell, you must provide the row height in the delegate since the table view controls the frame for its rows.

Comment: Also note that `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` just returns you the NSLayoutConstraints but doesn't actually add them to the view. I suggest a good read of https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: Can you give crash log??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass string parameter in `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` You need to pass ASCII art-like visual format string so In the format `@"V:|-(5)-[self.username]-[self.postText]-(5)-|"` that you created `self.username`, `self.postText` should be of type id.